# Video Quality on YouTube Android Player API

Tags: youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am trying to develop an app using Android's YouTube API.  I want to manually modify the video quality but I was not able to find any relevant API, any help is appreciated.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/package-summary

Thanks,
Ankur

Answer (score 2):

There is not a method to modify the quality right now, it uses the default settings. Feel free to follow revision history if it comes along in the future 'https://developers.google.com/youtube/feeds/android-player-api-revision-history.xml'

Comment: What do you mean by default settings. What settings is default setting?

Comment: Best setting for the device, connection