# How to set Youtube API Android playback video quality

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Hey guys I have searched a lot but couldn't find a solution for setting the default video quality of 240p for Youtube Android API using Youtube Player View but no luck finding a solution need help.

Comment: There is not a method to modify the quality [check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720967/video-quality-on-youtube-android-player-api) this question

Comment: You can use IFrame API, as @AniketBhoite stated it is not available using YT Android API. Use Iframe API with an Android WebView and then, control the video quality as stated in this related SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19292476/5995040). Hope it helps.